# How to disable Alt-Tab shortcut in VMPlayer?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, vmware-player, alt-tab

I want to send Alt-Tab to my windows host OS when working out of the guest OS on VM player. At the minute it gets trapped by the guest OS. Anyway to disable sending it to the guest (RedHat)?

Answer (score -1):

Go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\VMware\`, then open your `preferences.ini` file.

Add the following lines to the file:

```
pref.hotkey.shift = “true”
pref.hotkey.control = “true”
pref.hotkey.alt = “true”
```

This will change the release hotkeys to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

For more information regarding hotkeys check [this document](http://sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-preferences-ini.html).

Comment: that didn't appear to work with a vm I suspended, shut down player, made change, restarted and reloaded?

Comment: Have you really tried that key combination? The message below your VM will allways tell you to use Alt-Tab to return focus to your host-OS. But the key combination you set should work.

Comment: Hey @idavid - when editing posts, please make sure to make _substantial_ edits. Just adding `<kbd>` markup is not enough to make it worth changing a post. It's better to focus editing efforts on things like improving spelling/grammar, formatting completely unformatted (i.e. wall of text) posts, etc. It looks like you've made a large number of edits that consisted _solely_ of adding `<kbd>`, which makes the post look nice, but isn't really improving the content. This type of editing should be done in addition to more substantial edits you're already making, not as the sole purpose of the edit.

Comment: @nhinkle sorry about that but they do look good with that i didn't mean to mess up stuffs i am new here i didn't know the rules

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question and should be removed. The question (which I'm also interested in) was how to prevent the guest OS from receiving the Alt-TAB key combination. The answer here just says how to change the release focus key combination, which has nothing to do with the question.