# "Alt-Tab" out of VMWare Workstation, without having to "release" controls first?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vmware

Using VMWare Workstation, by default once the virtual machine is focused, it grabs *all* user input until a configured hotkey is pressed -- defaulting to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>.

As a consequence, in order to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of guest OS, I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Since I use the VM only to run Microsoft Office apps, and otherwise work in the host OS, this is inconvenient, since I need to switch frequently.

Is it possible to instead make VMWare *not* capture <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and instead have it interpreted directly by the host OS, *without* having to press a "release focus" hotkey first?

---

There is a near-equivalent question [How to disable Alt-Tab shortcut in VMPlayer?](https://superuser.com/questions/598480/how-to-disable-alt-tab-shortcut-in-vmplayer). It does however not ask for  a solution that doesn't require releasing the keyboard capturing before <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>ing.

If I were using a Linux Guest on a Windows Host, I could use "Seamless" or "Unity" mode to achieve essentially what I am asking for and more. On a Linux Host, this feature is sadly no longer supported.

Comment: I think the closet you can get is changing the release control to be alt+tab and just press it twice. Edit > Preferences > Hot Keys. Not a solution, but arguably quicker than the default release + alt tabbing after

Comment: @Narzard Sadly, VMWare only allows the keys `Alt`, `Ctrl`, `Shift` and `Win`. Setting it to `Alt+Tab` is not offered. Sadly, this restriction is even mirrored by how it is stored in the configuration files.

Comment: `Switch to console view` fixed my ctrl-tab issue: https://i.imgur.com/vd5V0SW.png

Comment: @goksel What difference does this make for you? For me that Icon is called "Switch to the virtual machine's summary view", and while clicking it does release input from the VM context, it is no improvement over pressing the "release focus" hotkey. https://i.imgur.com/xYLf6GJ.png